# How to plot the contour of a function on an arbitrary domain?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on functions defined on non-rectangular grids and wonder if there is a simple way of displaying a two dimensional `countourf`-plot. Sure, I could work something out by creating a rectangular grind and masking the values that are not on my desired domain, but I really look for something simple that works for any case that might occur.

Right now, I use `scatter` for a mosaic-like picture:

```py
ax.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], c=z, s=15, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
```

where `coords` stores the **x** and **y** coordinates and `z` the values of my considered function. That means, for a function sampled with **N** points, `coords` has shape (N, 2) and `z` has shape (N).

[image]

Comment: `ax.tricontourf(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], z, levels=256, cmap='inferno')` should produce a reasonable result provided the domain is convex

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something ...